# Maximally extended solution of this ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am asked to find the *positive*, *maximally extended* solutions to this ODE.

$$u'(x) = \frac{x}{u(x)}$$

Now a solution is given by

$$u(x) = (\int_{y_0}^y t dt )^{-1}\circ \int_{x_0}^x s ds = G^{-1} \circ F$$

Now, I have to be carful here and consider a few things.
so first off,

$$u(x) = \sqrt{x^2-(x_0^2-y_0^2)}$$
and $R(F) = [\frac{-x_0^2}{2},\infty),D(G^{-1}) =[-y_0^2/2,\infty) $

If $x_0^2 > y_0^2 \implies D(G^{-1}) \subset R(F)$
I have a feeling this is a good thing.

I am a bit foggy on how to move on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get $$u(x) = \sqrt{x^2-(x_0^2-y_0^2)}$$ you only need to consider the inequality $$x^2>x_0^2-y_0^2.$$

Now, if $x_0^2<y_0^2$ then the solution is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ If $x_0^2=y_0^2$ then the solution is defined in $(0,\infty)$ if $x_0>0$ or in $(-\infty,0)$ if $x_0<0.$ Finally, if $x_0^2>y_0^2$ then the solution is defined in $(\sqrt{x_0^2-y_0^2},\infty)$ if $x_0>0$ or in $(-\infty,-\sqrt{x_0^2-y_0^2})$ if $x_0<0.$